# Cannot execute a python script from php inside an if-else statement

Tags: php, python, apache, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I am on raspberry pi and i am using an apache server. The PHP code will execute the python script if id in the url is even. The python script runs perfectly fine when it is outside the if-else block.

```
<?php
$op=shell_exec("python /home/pi/hi.py");
echo $op;

$id = intval($_GET["id"]);
echo $id."\n";
?>
```

But when placed in the if-else block it fails to work.

```
<?php    
$id = intval($_GET["id"]);
echo $id."\n";

if($id%2==0)
echo "Even";
$op=shell_exec("python /home/pi/hi.py");
echo $op;
else
echo "Odd";   
?>
```

I am new to php and I cannot seem to understand the problem.

Comment: You're also going to need some brackets for your if/else because you have multiple statements after the if.

Comment: Oh thanks. Missed the simplest thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`else` is actually a syntax error in this case. Without braces around the statements after `if`, PHP expects *one* statement to follow it. Since there are more than one, the `else` is unexpected when it is reached.

Adding the braces should fix the problem.

```
if ($id%2==0) {
    echo "Even";
    $op=shell_exec("python /home/pi/hi.py");
    echo $op;
} else {
    echo "Odd";
}
```

Generally, I think it's a good idea to just *always* use the braces, even if you do have only one statement. That way when you add more statements later, you won't run into this problem.